# Accessing utility methods from any class instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c

*(This has probably been answered elsewhere but I don't know what to search on to find it)*

I have the `printErrorMessage` method below which I find very useful. I've been including it in all my classes but that is kind of dumb in terms of duplicating code. Can I just define this as a Class method in a separate Utility class?

This is on iOS, if that matters.

```
- (void) printErrorMessage: (NSString *) errorString withStatus: (OSStatus) result
{
    char str[20];
    // see if it appears to be a 4-char-code
    *(UInt32 *)(str + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(result);
    if (isprint(str[1]) && isprint(str[2]) && isprint(str[3]) && isprint(str[4])) {
        str[0] = str[5] = '\'';
        str[6] = '\0';
    } else
        // no, format it as an integer
        sprintf(str, "%d", (int)result);

    NSLog (@"*** %@ error: %s\n", errorString, str);
}
```

Comment: You can do whatever you want. Static method, singleton, compiler macro, C function... Personally I'd make ti a C function, the same as NSLog.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just define this as a Class method in a separate Utility class?

Of course you can. That is what class methods are for. Alternatively, inject it into some existing class by way of a category.

Comment: On behalf of [uday](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5150586): Additionally you can include the header file in your <ProjectName>.pch file, so that all files in the project automatically include the file. Since its a logging header file, most files need it and shouldn't increase your compile times substantially.

Answer (score 0):

I use to create a class with static methods:

```
@interface Utils

+ (void) printErrorMessage: (NSString *) errorString withStatus: (OSStatus) result

@end
```

Now you can call this from anywhere in your code using:

```
[Utils printErrorMessage:@"string" withStatus:status];
```